# Concat and join

Tags: sql, join, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate this table and join two more tables.
My output should contain the column: Customers Full Name(first and last name),Product Description, Quantity Ordered.

```
Table Name Customers:
CustomerId
FirstName 
Lastname
City 
State
```

```
Table Name: Orders
OrderNo
CustomerId
ProductID
Quantity
```

```
Table: Products
ProductID
Description
Quantity
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming none of the customer id or product ids can be null so doing inner joins.

```
SELECT C.FirstName + ' ' + C.LastName AS [FullName],
       P.Description AS [ProductDescription],
       O.Quantity AS [QuantityOrdered]
  FROM Orders O
  JOIN Customers C
    ON C.CustomerId = O.CustomerId
  JOIN Products P
    ON P.ProductId = O.ProductId
```